# why does chrome.runtime.lastError not enter

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, hid

I have not connected this VID / PID device on the computer
But why does chrome.runtime.lastError not enter?

```
var enumerateDevices = function() {
  chrome.hid.getDevices({"vendorId":11368,"productId":57349}, onDevicesEnumerated);
  chrome.hid.onDeviceAdded.addListener(onDeviceAdded);
  chrome.hid.onDeviceRemoved.addListener(onDeviceRemoved);
};

var onDevicesEnumerated = function(devices) {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.error("Unable to enumerate devices: " +
                  chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    return;
  }

  for (var device of devices) {
    onDeviceAdded(device);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because not having a device that matches the filter is not considered to be an error by the API.

Nothing in [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/hid#method-getDevices) suggests that this is an error condition.

`devices` will be defined and empty, which you can test for.

Comment: Thanks.  and I have another question. "chrome.hid.send()" method, if I use the wrong reportId ,wrong connectionId or not allowed array data to send,I have not any judge,and console log have this error"Unchecked runtime.lastError: Transfer failed."... How do I judge this send error ? I need to catch this error and decide if next step is executed.